# Extendable/efficient solution for finding specific sub-types

Tags: design-patterns, data-structures

There is a Room class. It contains list of furniture; chairs, table & etc. It is required to retrieve list of chairs only. Keeping separate list for each types of furniture is not an extendable solution. (For example adding a new furniture type requires new type of list creation & so on.) But having a single list and updating it requires to iterate through all the furniture and find out the chairs only with the help of instance of operator or any other ways.

How to design such an implementation efficiently with design pattern or data-structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to search for chairs efficiently through some uniform aggregate, then either you use:

1. The inextensible solution you cited
2. An extensible one with the furniture type being a key to a
   multimap-style data structure (one that allows different values
   under the same key)
3. A hybrid kind of solution.

You already know about the inextensible one so let's skip that.

For #2, you can use the type of furniture as a key to an associative data structure which allows entries with duplicate keys but differing values. An example from C++ would be `multimap`. You could rely on type information obtained at runtime as a key if the language supports it, or a solution like this:

```
class Furniture
{
public:
    virtual ~Furniture() {}
    virtual SomeKeyType key() const = 0;
};

class Chair: public Furniture
{
public:
    virtual SomeKeyType key() const override 
    {
        return "chair"; // note: doesn't have to be a string.
    }
};
```

Now whenever you insert furniture to a room, insert it into this associative structure using this `key` as a search key. Now when you want to search for chairs, search for items with a `chair` key. This can easily be done in logarithmic time or better.

The #3 hybrid-style solution is basically a `multimap` design of your own. You can design an aggregate which takes a key and uses the appropriate list based on the key provided when searching, inserting, removing, iterating. This extra control might be of some benefit if you know you don't have too many furniture types, for example, and don't need a full-blown tree structure or hash table and can simply have a bunch of lists created at runtime based on a key provided.

Those are typically your main choices. If you use an RDBMS, it would already have these kinds of features built in with the underlying data structures it uses. If you roll your own, typically it's one of the three above in terms of the fundamental mechanics.